# how can scraping pagination pages uisng php

Tags: php

I'm trying to scraping pagination pages , i don't know the number of pagination pages its a next button with out count When the pages are finished, this button disappears.
i tried to make loop with number but this method make scrapping takes too long time.
is there an idea to know number of pagination or make fanctiion to check if there's a "next" button in the page or any idea ?

this'is my code :

```
function getUrls($url){
        $fbPost = grab_page($url);
        $postUsers = new simple_html_dom();
        $postUsers->load($fbPost);
        //$nextPage = $postUsers->find('#m_story_permalink_view div',0)->outertext;

    foreach($postUsers->find('#m_story_permalink_view h3 a') as $fbUserDiv) {
     $data = $fbUserDiv->href;
      //echo $data."<br>";
     $myData = $data."\n";
      file_put_contents("usersUrl.txt",$myData,FILE_APPEND);
    }
    // return $arr;

}

for($i=0;$i<=100;$i++){
    $pagenum=$i;
    $zeroNum = "0";
    if ($pagenum>=9) {
        $zeroNum = "";
    }
 getUrls("sitexample.com?p=".$i.$zeroNum);
}
```

Comment: If there is any endpoint for that - yes, otherwise - no, you have to loop till all items returned

Comment: If you are trying to scrape the html, then you need some knowledge of html.  If you know how to search for an h3 tag, then why can't you search for a button.